# Azure app service - unable to create certificate

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, certificate

Add App Service Managed Certificate
Error adding managed certificate: Pending managed certificate failed: Certificate creation was rejected by CA for canonical name application2.elasticcart.com: A CNAME record was found but does not point to a whitelisted domain. If retrying does not help, please contact support for assistance. Refer to the documentations for more info: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2158627.

I get this error wile creating certificate on App Service. I have TXT and CNAME records on my domain DNS Record. don't know that reasons. Please Let me know what is the workaround for this.

Comment: Please let me know which service plan you are using in azure web apps.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the issue and able to resolve, please follow the below steps

1. Create an Azure web app

[image]

2. After creating Webapp Goto **Custom domain** and select **Buy app service domain** take the reference from below picture

[image]

3. After clicking **Buy app service domain** you will redirect to page which is show below
4. select the **Subscription name**, **resource group** and enter the **domain name** it will show available domain name below

[image]

5. After the above steps click review and create. it will create a domain to web app you have selected
6. After that there will be a certificate creation Goto **TLS/SSL setting** and select **private key certificates (.pfx)** and select **Create App Service managed certificate** and select the **domain name** and click on **create** it will create a certificate on selected domain name

[image]
7.  After the above step we have to bind the certificate with the domain name as shown below

[image]
it worked for me.